# Browserify with Ionic for WooCommerceAPI

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, browserify

I am trying to use the [woocommerce-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api) node module in my Ionic+ AngularJS App. I have used browserify to build one huge `js` file with WoocommerceAPI and all its dependencies. I have referenced the file in my index.html. But I still get the following error when I try to create an object of the **WooCommerceAPI** in my controller code.

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: WooCommerceAPI is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:28)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17762)
    at extend.instance (ionic.bundle.js:22311)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21421)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20853)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20857)
    at publicLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20728)
    at ionic.bundle.js:14947
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29257)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.